# Can White win in this game (Q vs R+N+P)?

Tags: learning, endgame

[image]

Is there any percent chance for the white to win?
Seems like greed for the opposite queen on behalf of sacrificing his pieces has cost him this game.

The view is from the white player's end.

Comment: In which direction does the pawn move? The location of captured pieces suggests that the players would sit on the right and left respectively, however in that case the board is put incorrectly (would have to be rotated 90 degrees or square colors exchanged: dark<-->light

Comment: All positions with 7 or fewer pieces on the board have been solved exactly. This means, that (once you figure out which direction the board is oriented), you could ask the endgame tablebase and it will tell you who is winning (or draw) and how many moves to mate with perfect play from both sides. Nothing like "chance" if you want an answer like this.

Comment: If you ask about "practical chance" in a game by humans, then yes, there is always a chance for players to blunder and lose. However, even the endgame queen vs rook and knight is an easy draw most of the time (unless the knight is far away and on its own which is not the case here) and any reasonably advanced player would easily make a draw. Adding a pawn can only give black winning chances.

Comment: this view is from the white player's end

Comment: FWIW, 'K' is usually reserved for the king. For the kNight we use an N.

Comment: Nepo, did you travel back in time to post this question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there is no chance for white to draw, let alone win, this game. In fact, if you enter this into an endgame tablebase it will tell you that it is mate in 13 moves with perfect play from both sides. One possible line is:

```
8/4K3/8/4Q3/8/4nk2/3p4/4r3 w - - 0 1

1. Qh5+ Ng4+ 2. Kd6 d1=Q+ 3. Qd5 Qxd5+ 4. Kxd5 Rd1+ 5. Kc5 Ke4 6. Kc6  Ne5+ 7. Kc5 Rd2 8. Kb5 Kd4 9. Kb6 Rb2+ 10. Kc7 Kd5 11. Kd8 Kd6 12. Kc8 Rb1 13. Kd8 Rb8++
```

Even if you don't have a tablebase, the position is quite obviously won for black. White's only hope in this position would be if he could capture the black pawn or if there was perpetual check. Neither of this is possible here, basically because all black pieces are working together and can protect each other and (and this is **important**), black is threatening a discovered check/pin which helps to prevent perpetual checks: basically if white checks with the queen black's knight can block the check, while at the same time giving check himself, thereby gaining a tempo for queening the pawn.

If you moved the white king away from this pin, it might very well be draw by perpetual check. For instance the same position with the white king on b8 is a draw.

Answer (score 4):

If, as you claim, it's viewed from White's side, then the black pawn is almost promoted and according to [Shredder](http://www.shredderchess.com/online-chess/online-databases/endgame-database.html), White will even *lose* in 13 moves or less.

[image]

<sub>(no time right now to analyze/post variations, sorry)</sub>

Comment: There is no much need for analysis. Any check by the queen can be intercepted by the knight with a discovered counter-check. On the next move the pawn queens and Black's material advantage is overwhelming and decisive.